# Sort list of lists using LINQ so high score is first then lastname and firstname in alphabetic order

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have this code

```
 Person[] peopleArray = new Person[5]
   {
      new Person("John", "Jones", "001", 1450),
      new Person("Jimmy", "Smith", "004", 1237),
      new Person("Sue", "Baker", "002", 1534),
      new Person("Chuck", "Smith", "003", 1450),
      new Person("Toby", "Jones", "005", 1450)
   };

 var sortedPeopleList = peopleArray.OrderBy(a => a.score).ThenBy(a => a.lastName)
                                              .ThenBy(a => a.firstName).Reverse();

 foreach (Person p in sortedPeopleList)
 Console.WriteLine(p.score + " " + p.id + " " + p.firstName + " " + p.lastName );
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Output is:

> 1534 002 Sue Baker
>
> 1450 003 Chuck Smith  <= this should be #4
>
> 1450 005 Toby Jones   <= this should be #3
>
> 1450 001 John Jones   <= this should be #2
>
> 1237 004 Jimmy Smith

Desired output must be sorted by Score (descending), 
then last name (ascending), finally last name (ascending)

1

> 534 002 Sue Baker
>
> 1450 001 John Jones
>
> 1450 005 Toby Jones
>
> 1450 003 Chuck Smith
>
> 1237 004 Jimmy Smith

Any suggestions would be helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` have partner methods `OrderByDescending` and `ThenByDescending`.

So now you can eliminate `Reverse` and go with:

```
peopleArray.OrderByDescending(a => a.score)
           .ThenBy(a => a.lastName)
           .ThenBy(a => a.firstName);
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I didn't realize there was an OrderByDescending method.  Thanks so much @spender. :-)